# Reshaping matrix into vector of alternate columns

Tags: r, matrix, format

I have a matrix measuring 91 x 2 (i.e 91 rows and two columns).

```
 mat1 <- matrix(1:182, 91, 2)
```

I need to create a vector from the said matrix of one row. I can do that with the following:

`mat2 <- matrix(mat1, nrow = 1, byrow = TRUE)`.

However, I would like to have each row in the original matrix to be represented one after another. Currently it's taking all of column 1 then all of column 2 and joining those together sequentially. Whilst I need them to be in one long row, like this: `1,92,2,93,3,94 etc`Meaning the structure ultimately would be `1,182` (i.e. one row with 182 columns).

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can transpose the matrix and convert it to a vector

```
c(t(mat1))
```